# Insert word table caption vba: title character limit

Tags: vba, vbscript, ms-word

I have a very simple function which takes strings from variable `txt` and covert it into a title using `InsertCaption`. At this moment, I can pass a really long string (way over 255 characters) into this function, but somehow, `InsertCaption` still truncates my variable `txt` and limit the size to 255. So is there a way to work this around? Can I hack this function? Thanks!

```
appWD.Selection.InsertCaption Label:=Lbl, _
                              Title:=txt & txt, _
                              Position:=0, _
                              ExcludeLabel:=0   'wdCaptionPositionAbove = 0
```

Comment: Which version of Word is this? Are you able to create a caption longer than 255 characters in the Word UI, as a user? Word does have some 255 character limitations, especially in VBA,  but I don't know if this is one of them and am not on a machine where I can research that, at the moment...

Comment: @CindyMeister, thanks for the comment. I am using Word 2013 in Windows 7. I have to create the long caption in VBA. So far I am trying to split the string and insert the remain part using `TypeText`

Comment: I asked about the UI for testing purposes, not as a solution.

Comment: @CindyMeister, just tried, it did not generate an error message but I could not tell whether or not WORD consider the long string as caption or not...

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a limitation in Word VBA. There are a number of them that limit text to 255 characters, that come from the early, WordBasic days. (The VBA object model overlays the old WordBasic.)

One way to work around this problem is to check whether the string assigned to the caption is longer than 255 characters. If it is, append the remainder to the caption. For example:

```
Sub InsertCaptionLongerThan255Chars()
    Dim tbl As Word.Table
    Dim sCapText As String
    Dim rngCap As word.Range

    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    sCapText = String(400, "x")
    tbl.Range.InsertCaption "Table", sCapText
    If Len(sCapText) > 255 Then
        'The selection in the document moves to the new caption
        Set rngCap = Selection.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range
        'Put the target at the end of the caption's paragraph
        rngCap.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        rngCap.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
        'Add the remainder of the text
        rngCap.Text = Mid(sCapText, 256)
    End If
End Sub
```